How to make HubSpot lifecycle conversions to LinkedIn
I have connected LinkedIn ad account to HubSpot and created conversion events from there to LinkedIn like in the documentation: https://knowledge.hubspot.com/ads/create-and-sync-ad-conversion-events-with-your-linkedin-ads-account 
Now that I have created those conversion in HubSpot, how I can see them in the LinkedIn? Do I need create conversion through conversion API in LinkedIn?

I tried to verify LinkedIn account in HubSpot again to see the HubSpot conversion events in LinkedIn.
I created a conversion through conversion API in LinkedIn to see how it works. Confusing part in here is how I can differentiate between different events and are they even connected to events that I have created in HubSpot. Now there is only two events that are named 'HubSpot Offline Conversion Events'
Events I can choose from when creating conversion through the Conversion API in LinkedIn


This was solved by HubSpot Support!
